# Define python struct value as struct itself

Tags: python, struct

I'm trying to create a resulting struct based on input struct. Code looks similar to this:

```
  from google.protobuf.struct_pb2 import Struct
  resulting_struct = Struct()
  for key, value in input_struct.items():
      if value != '':
          resulting_struct[key] = value
```

It works fine except of one moment:

If the type of 'value' is Struct, I receive `'ValueError: Unexpected type'`. Error is based on '_SetStructValue' function in `'google/protobuf/internal/well_known_types.py'`.

Is there a way to handle this issue and provide creation of nested structures?

Comment: Please share your proto file

Comment: well_known_types.py can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k2BUFrYPOfzXw76iftHxtBJWeh8W-WNz/view?usp=sharing